# Scope of h:commandButton and h:commandLink

Tags: jsf, button, command-line, action

What is the scope of h:commandButton, h:commandLink in a xhtml page?
   I tried to define these tags outside the h:form tags, it doesn't work? why is it so?

Comment: They are not part of XHTML. You might want to edit your question to add some information about where they come from.

Answer (score 2):

As Quentin already said that these are not basic part of an xhtml file. These are components that can be used to build functional document.

Well according to documentation,

The `h:commandButton` tag renders an HTML submit button that can be associated with a backing bean or ActionListener class for event handling purposes."

REF: http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/html/h_commandButton.html

And the `h:commandLink` tag generates a link act like a submit button when clicked. The “value” attribute is rendered as the anchor text, “action” attribute is determined the target URL of the HTML “href” attribute.

REF: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink-example/

**I tried to define these tags outside the h:form tags, it doesn't work? why is it so?**

Because, as these both are submit type, they require a GET/POST method of form invoked in their corresponding survlet. That is why, they will be non-functional when they are used outside of the form.

Refer documentation for further understanding.